# Shaders very slow on intel HD Graphics card

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

I was trying to write a fragment shader which uses an uniform array ( as i need lots of values in my shader which are consistent across the invocation) . I am trying this on webgl , so can't use uniformbuffers for packing lot of uniforms . I could have used 2D textures for packing those uniforms , but some values of the uniforms would cross 255 , so i need to use floating point textures which are not widely available , specially on mobiles . So i had to stick to the approach of using uniform array . 
My fragment shader code has the declaration as :

```
uniform float array[100];
```

Now with an array of size 100 on an Intel HD graphics card the performance drops down by 50% , but on nvdia cards that's not the case . I had queried the `MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS` which comes out to be `221` in my case .
I tried with different sizes of this array and had seen a very weird  behavior.

If the size of the array exceeds 81 , suddenly the performance drops by 50% . 
Did anyone ever face this problem ? Is there a way to resolve this ? 
Please note in browsers, only shader version 1.0 is supported ( #version 100) .